How to avoid other objects resizing when an object rotates?
it's a strange little bug that looks a bit weird, I'm not sure why the other elements resize when the hover animation rotates the element
i've tried not using rotation, but only scaling the element seems to make the other elements resize too. the same happens when i'm only rotating and not scaling the element.
i seems both scaling and rotating the element makes the other elements stretch and resize. i still want to animate the elements when I hover over them, but how do I stop the weird resizing?


.float {
  background-color: #b6c4a4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #73846a;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* margin: 15px; */
  margin: 0.75%;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.float:hover {
  background-color: #cdddbd;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  rotate: -1 -1 -1 5deg;
  margin-top: 25px;
  scale: 1.02;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.cards {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
<div class="cards">
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 1a</h3>
        <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 2a</h3>
        <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 3a</h3>
    <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 1b</h3>
        <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 2b</h3>
    <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 3b</h3>
        <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
</div>




The problem is caused by changing the font-size on :hover. Increasing the font size means that the line height increases proportionally, and therefore the card itself needs to grow vertically to accommodate, affecting the layout of the entire line and causing everything below the line to shift.
Run the snippet below to see how a paragraph layout is affected by increasing the font size of a single word. The line containing the large word must grow to accommodate it, whether or not transforms are applied to the word.


span {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
}

.s2 {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel <span>facilisis</span> ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. <span class="s2">Morbi</span> ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.</p>



In your case, the problem is exacerbated because in your .cards flexbox you have not set a value for align-items. You can set this to start or end (the default value of normal behaves as stretch for flex items) to prevent other cards in the same line from changing size.
The fix I would recommend is to limit your :hover styling to properties which do not affect the layout, such as transform, background-color and box-shadow. Instead of changing the font size, you could simply apply a larger scale.


.cards {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.float {
  background-color: #b6c4a4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #73846a;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0.75%;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.float:hover {
  background-color: #cdddbd;
  transform: scale(1.15) rotate(-5deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
}
<div class="cards">
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 1a</h3>
        <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 2a</h3>
        <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 3a</h3>
    <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 1b</h3>
        <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 2b</h3>
    <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
  <a class="float card" href="https://github.com">
    <h3>EXAMPLE 3b</h3>
        <p>example paragraph. blah blah blah.</p>
    </a>
</div>




thanks! also, it turns out that i had margin-top: 25px; for some reason, so after I removed that as well as the font size, it worked!
